# How Can I get data from database by specific id range like id(1-3) in a table?

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, query-builder

Actually I need some specific data from a table, ID in range 1 - 5. How can I get this?

```
$products = Products::with('products_images')
                      ->select(['id', 'title','price', 'slug'])
                      ->where('id', 1,2,3)
                      ->get();
```

Comment: You should tag the framework that you're using

Comment: It's not any framework only MVC and PHP

Comment: So you're telling me that you wrote your own database abstraction layer, but don't know about `IN`, `BETWEEN`, or `>= and <=`?  Your code strongly implies that you're using something like Laravel, CodeIgniter, or Symfony

Comment: Looks like laravels eloquent ORM. Search for `whereBetween()` and `whereIn()`.

Comment: Thanks  @ Paul Spiegel

Comment: @Joxs  So you're confirming that you _are_ using Laravel?

Comment: No I am using eloquent ORM in MVC

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC.

Comment: @tereško  I rather agree with you, but why remove the `eloquent` tag when the question is quite specific to that library?

Comment: @PatrickQ my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally in SQL it works like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `id` > 1000 AND `id` < 2000
```

Regards Tom